# hiding only the selected component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hides only the selected component. I am unable to hide only a specific component

```
useEffect(() => { result() }, []);
const dataComponent = state.data.map((video, index) => {
    return <>
        <p onClick={() => showMoreInfo(!showing)}>show</p>
        {showing 
            ? <ContainerFilmHome key={index} name={video.show_name} pictures={video.pictures}/> 
            : null}
    </>
})
```

Comment: What do you mean with "selected"?

Comment: Explain the use case with more information.

Comment: I will have multiple items returned. But when you click show, all elements will be shown. And I only need to show the pressed element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need update `showing` to store index of item selected:

```
onClick={() => showMoreInfo(index === showing ? null : index)}

{showing === index
    ? <ContainerFilmHome key={index} name={video.show_name} pictures={video.pictures}/> 
    : null}
```